# What is the "proper" tag prefix for the AjaxControlToolkit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, naming-conventions

I've seen many examples where they just use the "asp" prefix.  Is this a good practice?

(The reason I'm asking is because the templates that create the default for a new website appear to be problematic.  There's an apparent naming collision on the BulletedList control.)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no "best practice" for that. I usually use the company name for the control sets. For the MS Ajax and AjaxToolKit I use "ajax" as prefix, because it's short and different that "asp".

For the controls I develop where I work, I use "esi" because that is the abbreviation. That's the only one reason.

Answer (score 2):

I like the prefix **act**.

I would definitely recommend against using **asp** as the prefix for anything other than the base ASP.NET WebControls.